# Extracting file extension in Python: os.path.splitext vs re.sub

Tags: python

I often needs to extract the extension of a file in `Python`. The code we often see on the web for such task is using `os.path.splitext`:

```
fpath = "C:/I/am/hap.py"
ext = os.path.splitext(fpath)[-1]
```

Is there any reason why this would be better than using `re.sub` (which is easy to remember)?

```
fpath = "C:/I/am/hap.py"
ext = re.sub(r'.*\.', '.', fpath)
```

*Note: same number of characters in each solution :)*

Comment: If see `ext = os.path.splitext(fpath)[-1]`, I know exactly what you're doing, even if I don't know the contents of `fpath`.  If I see `ext = re.sub(r'.*\.', '.', fpath)`, there's nothing there that tells me that you're dealing with filenames, and while it's a simple regular expression it's not as immediately obvious as the path operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather opinionated question (and so too the answer), but IMO:

1.) Code readability.  The `splitext` is documented and easy to look up to know exactly what the code is doing, where as `re.sub` is substituting *something* to a `"."`, but now you need to parse that regex before you understand what's happening.

2.) No extraneous `import`s.  For codes that doesn't have regex usage anywhere else, you don't need to `import re`, whereas if your code is meant for tinkering system files, you would most likely already be using `import os` or `from os import path` already.

3.) KISS.  You could achieve the same result with a lot of different ways (e.g. `ext = fpath[fpath.rfind('.'):]` or `ext = f'.{fpath.split(".")[-1]}'` which are both even shorter in characters), but in general, if there was already a built in function to help achieve it, don't reinvent the wheel unless you have a perfectly good reason.

Comment: ... and the fact that `re.sub` does not work with files without extensions (and there are a lot in *Nix systems).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 2 things

- It is easier to understand that it is a file manipulation and its purpose (as mentioned by @larsks
- `os.path.splitext` will support the case where there is no extension:

For example, with a `Makefile`:

```
>>> fpath = "C:/Dir/Makefile"
>>> os.path.splitext(fpath)[-1]
''
>>> re.sub(r'.*\.', '.', fpath)
'C:/Dir/Makefile'
```

Comment: With `pathlib`, it's just `Path(fpath).suffix`.

Answer (score -1):

The `os` module was meant to handle all sorts of scenarios. Specifically in your case some OSes uses `\` vs `/` along with other nomenclature unique to that OS.

If you did it with regex you would have to account for all the possibilities and edge cases.